# Max Area Under the Curve with $y = \sqrt{6-x}$

Tags: calculus, radicals, area

I see a lot of examples without radicals for $y$, but I'm not finding the solution to the answer for this one at all. Although I know the answer is supposed to be $4\sqrt 2$.

> [image]
>
> Consider a rectangle in the $xy$-plane with its lower-left vertex at the origin and its upper-right
> vertex on the graph of $y = \sqrt{6-x}$ as indicated in the figure above. What is the maximum area
> of such a rectangle?

My current approach:

$y = \sqrt{6-x}$

$A = x \sqrt{6-x}$

$A' = \sqrt{6-x} + \left(x\cdot\frac 1 2\cdot(6-x)^{-\frac 1 2}\right)$

$A' = \sqrt{6-x} + \dfrac x {2\sqrt{6-x}}$

$A' = \dfrac {2(6-x) + x} {2\sqrt{6-x}} = \dfrac {12-x+x} {2\sqrt{6-x}} = \dfrac 6 {\sqrt{6-x}}$

If I set $x = 0$, $x$ then becomes zero, which I know is not correct.

**Update**

$A' = \sqrt{6-x} - \dfrac x {2\sqrt{6-x}}$

$A' = \dfrac {2(6-x) - x} {2\sqrt{6-x}}$

$A' = \dfrac {12-2x-x} {2\sqrt{6-x}} = \dfrac {12-3x} {2\sqrt{6-x}} = \dfrac {3(4-x)} {2\sqrt{6-x}}$

$0 = \dfrac {3(4-x)} {2\sqrt{6-x}} $

$x = 4$

$A = 4\sqrt{6-4} = 4\sqrt 2$

Comment: You say you see a lot of other examples, but without the radical. How do those answers proceed? Is it possible to proceed the same way here? What's stopping you?

Comment: You're just trying to maximise $x \sqrt {6 - x}$. Do you know how to find maxima using calculus?

Comment: I set the Area = x(√6-x) like most examples I see, then I try to find the first derivative, and set that equal to zero to find x, but I keep getting a long derivative, and when I set to 0, I get x =0, but I know that it's not. I think I'm just not approaching it correctly.

Comment: Can you post your working? The derivative is not particularly ugly. Your approach is fine but I would guess that your derivative is wrong

Comment: @GeorgeCoote I've added my current approach

Comment: Should be $\displaystyle \sqrt {6 - x} - \frac x {2 \sqrt {6 - x}}$ not $\displaystyle \sqrt {6 - x} + \frac x {2 \sqrt {6 - x}}$ as you wrote. Think chain rule.

Comment: @GeorgeCoote I see, thank you for catching that menial error for me! I was able to get the answer.